# Can numpy generate random numbers larger than 64 bits?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I'm trying to sample random numbers from the uniform distribution using [`numpy.random.randint`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html). Sometimes the size is larger than a 64-bit integer, though, and numpy chokes:

```py
>>> np.random.randint(0, 371993326789901217467999448150835200000000)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 991, in mtrand.RandomState.randint
ValueError: high is out of bounds for int64
```

I thought that this was why [`dtype`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/6910) was introduced, but it still gives the same error, no matter which type I try:

```py
>>> np.random.randint(0, 371993326789901217467999448150835200000000, dtype=np.long)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 991, in mtrand.RandomState.randint
ValueError: high is out of bounds for int64
```

Is there a way to do this with numpy? Or is there another way to accomplish this?

Comment: np.iinfo(np.int64)
…. yields …. iinfo(min=-9223372036854775808, max=9223372036854775807, dtype=int64)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about np.iinfo. That led me to the datatypes page for numpy, and it appears they don't support anything larger than int64. Oh well. I guess I'll use random.randrange for now.

Comment: If it doesn't have to be `numpy`, you could use the builtin `random` module, which gives you standard Python `int`s of arbitrary size when calling `random.randint`. All the normal calculation stuff like add, mult etc. will work - except for anything that comes from `numpy`.