# Random numbers for large populations

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a large population (`n_population>sys.maxsize`) to take `n_samples` different samples from, e.g.:

```py
n_population = 22256639186670493696
n_samples = 2
```

My first idea was to use [`sklearn.utils.random.sample_without_replacement`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.random.sample_without_replacement.html), because we use scikit-learn anyway and, what's more important, it allows me to define `random_state` for reproducing the results in a consistent way. However, it fails:

```py
sample_without_replacement(n_population=n_population, n_samples=n_samples)
# OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

I understand why it fails, but I've found no way to get around that with scikit-learn. So I turned to plain Python, using built-in [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample). However, it fails as well:

```py
random.sample(range(n_population), k=n_samples)
#OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C size_t
```

Ultimately, I've come up with workaround that works fine:

```py
samples = []
while len(samples) < n_samples:
    s = random.randint(0, n_population-1)
    if s not in sample:
        samples.append(s)
```

But it lacks `random_state`. Is there a better solution, preferably implemented on the top of scikit-learn?

Comment: You can use [random.seed](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.seed) to set the random state

Comment: @Sparky05 What's the relation between `random.seed `and scikit-learn `random_state`? It looks I would need to set both :-(

Comment: As far as I know, they are independent control values of the respective pseudo random number generators. However, you could easily create a method which sets both and you call this method every time (probably only once in your code) you need to fix the state.

Comment: As another remark you could get problems with your "random samples". I'm not sure what the precision the pseudo random number generators are. So if you're number range is maybe larger than these ranger (which would mean not any number within this range can be sampled at all). You should take a look at this. - just checked that its 53-bit long

Comment: @Sparky05 Thanks. My `n_population.bit_length()==65`, while *"all module functions depend on the basic function random()"* that *"produces 53-bit precision floats"*. Fortunately, `randint()` uses `randrange()` that can handle arbitrarily large ranges, thanks to `getrandbits()`.

Comment: With 65 bits you're exactly 1-bit over the `numpy` limit (which is as far as I could see used by sklearn), see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55155007/can-numpy-generate-random-numbers-larger-than-64-bits